# Is there a geometry library for Java? (not JTS)

Tags: java, geometry, computational-geometry

I'm hoping for the equivalent of CGAL (in C++)--I want convex partitioning of polygons or at least triangulation. It also has to be free. A previous question suggested [JTS](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/jtshome.htm), but it doesn't seem to have those functions.

Comment: I would advise anyone not to use JTS anyway for 3D geometry. It has a severe defect and it just doesn't calculate Z coordinates: intersection, union, areas... any operation of the sort in 3d doesn't work for that reason. 2D geometry seem to work though.

Answer (score 7):

JTS supports delaunay triangulation, but not constrained triangulation (holes):
http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.com/2009/04/delaunay-triangulation-in-jts-111.html

For constrained delaunay triangulation you can use [Poly2Tri](http://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/).
Works quite good, but could not triangulate polygons with holes, where the holes touch the outline or touch another polygon.

At the moment I use the OpenGl Tesselator (glut) with the java wrapper jogl (http://jogamp.org/) for triangulation in java.
You have to implement the correct callbacks and do some fiddling in there.

Neither of them satisfies all (my) needs, but until now I haven't found a better one.

Comment: I implemented a delaunay triangulation algorithm using JOGL and source code from http://www.informatik.uni-oldenburg.de/~trigger/ (ctrl+f triangle to find the relevant entry).  It's released under an educational/personal license, so it may not be useful for you, but it was good enough for me.

Answer (score 3):

GeoTools has a pretty extensive library of geometry manipulation algorithms, but of course just like JTS it is somewhat GIS-oriented.

http://www.geotools.org/

Answer (score 2):

CGAL has SWIG driven bindings since 2012. 2D conforming triangulation and meshes is part of it. Please visit the [github wiki](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal-swig-bindings/wiki) for furhter info's.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [`GeoLib`](http://www.geolib.co.uk) which is an excellent geometry package.

Comment: GeoLib is not free which was one of the constraints.